# Where in the complex plane is this function holomorphic and differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(x+iy)=\sqrt{|xy|}$$
First I try to see where the imaginary part and real part of this function satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$u(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$$
$$v(x,y)=0$$
Separating the absolute value into cases:

**Case 1: x$\geq$ 0,y$\geq$0**:

$u(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$, $v(x,y)=0$. Then $u_x(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$, and $u_y(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations read:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}=0$$
That are satisfied when $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Cases $x\geq0$ $y<0$,$x<0$ $y\geq0$ and $x<0$ $y<0$ give the same answer.

Now I have to see if the derivative at the origin exists using the definition of complex derivative:
$$f'(0)=Lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

Can somebody give me suggestions on how to solve that limit?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x+iy \to 0} \frac {\sqrt |xy|} {x+iy}$ does not exist. To see this put $y=x$ and note that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sqrt |x^{2}|} {x+ix}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {|x|} {(1+i)x}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {|x|} x$ does not exist because the right hand limit is $1$ and left hand limit is $-1$. Hence the function is not differentiable at $0$.